# Parsing the output of SGE's (qstat -j "*") using AWK or Perl

Tags: linux, perl, unix, awk

I have the output from SGE `qstat` command that looks like this: 
http://dpaste.com/1177012/plain/

It is obtained with the following command:

```
 $ qstat -j "*"
```

What I want to do is to parse the output of qstat -j "*" 
into table format:

```
#job_number submission_time owner usage
526715       Sat Apr 13 18:43:19 2013 yminakuc cpu=33:04:05:52, mem=2471753193.24440 GBs, io=619.41401, vmem=864.175G, maxvmem=920.232G
....
```

I was thinking to to create a code that can be used as pipe:

```
$ qstat -j "*" | ./mycodeparse.pl
```

What's the way to do it in AWK or Perl?
Or is there any available unix tool for that?

I'm stuck with the following construct (logic)

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w          
    use strict;                 
    use Data::Dumper;           

    my %hash;                   
    my $curr;

    while ( my $line = <> ) {   
        chomp $line;            


        if ( $line == /^=/ ) {  
           $hash{$line}=$curr = [];
        }
        elsif ( $line =~ /^job_number/ ||
                $line =~ /^owner/ || 
                $line =~ /^usage/ ||
                $line =~ /^submission_time/)) {
           push @$curr,$line;
         }

    }

    print Dumper \%hash ;
    #  Hash print everything instead of selected lines.
```

Comment: There's no tool that will do it automatically. Perl or awk scripts are perfect solutions to this. I hope you're hot expecting us to write it for you.

Comment: Can't you use `qstat -xml` and an XML parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That format is fairly close to [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/), so one option would be close the gap:

```
perl -lne 'BEGIN { print "---" } if (/^=/) { $new = 1; next } if ($new) { s/^/- /; $new = 0 } else { s/^/  / } print' paste > paste.yml
```

And then load it normally:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use common::sense;
use YAML 'LoadFile';

die "usage: $0 <file.yml>\n" unless @ARGV == 1;

my %jobs = map { $_->{job_number}, $_ } @{LoadFile(shift)};

say "#job_number submission_time owner usage";
for (keys %jobs) {
  say join("\t", $_, @{$jobs{$_}}{"submission_time", "owner", "usage    1"})
}
```

As the ugliness of that `"usage    1"` suggests, you might want to massage the keys as well.  The keys also vary as to names_with_underlines vs. 'names with spaces'.  Of course, you can key the `%jobs` hash on whatever value you want, or else skip building it and just process the arrayref:

```
for (@{LoadFile(shift)}) {
  say join("\t", @{$_}{"job_number", "submission_time", "owner", "usage    1"})
}
```

Output:

```
#job_number submission_time owner usage
5276175 Sat Apr 13 18:43:19 2013    yminakuc    cpu=33:04:05:52, mem=2471753193.24440 GBs, io=619.41401, vmem=864.175G, maxvmem=920.232G
606837  Fri Dec 14 19:20:55 2012    ataiba  
6252671 Wed May  8 23:08:22 2013    harukao cpu=9:13:06:40, mem=13115128.89679 GBs, io=19.38717, vmem=16.202G, maxvmem=19.131G
```

---

Regarding your edited-in attempt: the basic idea is very sound, but you make a few mistakes (trivial mistake: `==` instead of `=~` when matching `/^=/`; more significant mistake: keying your hash off the line of ='s, which is the same for every record, with the result that you only end up dumping the last record) and you miss a few tricks: f.e. you store unprocessed record lines instead of breaking them up into keys and values.

This alteration demonstrates: pushing hashes onto an array, and splitting the lines for only some of the keys:

```
if ( $line =~ /^=/ ) {  
  push @array, $curr = {};
}
elsif ( $line =~ / ^ (job_number
                    | owner
                    | usage
                    | submission_time)
                 .*?: \s* (.+)/x) {
  $curr->{$1} = $2
}
```

Excerpt of the dumped output:

```
{
    'usage' => 'cpu=33:04:05:52, mem=2471753193.24440 GBs, io=619.41401, vmem=864.175G, maxvmem=920.232G',
    'owner' => 'yminakuc',
    'job_number' => '5276175',
    'submission_time' => 'Sat Apr 13 18:43:19 2013'
},
```

With a small change you can store `$curr` into `%hash` with whatever key after you exhaust your input or run into another ==== line.